# Performance of filtering of a list in java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have `user` object that contains `address` object. Now I need to filter a list of users where address is not `null` and where city if London. Here is a code that do it.

```
users.stream()
   .filter(r -> r.getAddress() != null)
   .filter(r -> r.getAddress().getCity().equals("London"))
```

I'm thinking about performance of this. If I combine two statements will performance be better?

```
users.stream()
   .filter(r -> r.getAddress() != null && r.getAddress().getCity().equals("London"))
```

Comment: Yes.. writing the second condition is as expensive as writing the first one in cases where the first part does not pass.. so yes it will definitely be faster